# How to block program from executing before getting a response from a window layer on top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, oop

In my iPhone Application I have scenarios where there are multiple `windows` on the screen (note: not `UIViews` but `UIWindows`). These have some information and `UIButtons`. In a simple way think of these as `UIAlertViews` but with special functionalities which is why alerts were not sufficient. I have block of code to show this window inside a `for` loop like this:

```
 for (ObjectA *object in self.array) {
        if ([object.someValue isEqualToString:@"SomeString"]) {
            [self showResetMessageForObject:object];
        }
    }
 // SIGMA - further code here
```

and the method:

```
    - (void) showResetMessageForTender:(ObjectA*)object {
// some code here
    [resetMessageWindow performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3f];
    }
```

So when I call `showResetMessageForObject:` I want the execution of `SIGMA` to stop until I receive a button-click on the Window layer that is brought up by

```
[resetMessageWindow performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3f];
```

How can I achieve this? (note: 'SIGMA' is just place-holder for the readers)

Comment: It is unclear from your code what happens if self.array has multiple elements. Does it create multiple windows on top of eachother, and do you want to wait until the last window is closed?

Comment: No. In this scenario, only one object in self.array can have the value  "SomeString" at any given time. So this should only show one window at a time.

Comment: I think I found the answer. It was delegates.